# Read from Hbase + Convert to DF + Run SQLs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

**Edit**
My use case is a Spark streaming app (spark 2.1.1 + Kafka 0.10.2.1), wherein I read from Kafka and for each message/trigger need to pull data from HBase. post the pull, I need to run some SQL statements on the data (so received from HBase)

Naturally, I intend to push the processing (read from HBase & SQL execution) to the worker nodes to achieve parallelism.

So far, my attempts to convert the data from HBase to a data frame (so that i can launch SQK statements) are failing. Another gent mentioned that it's not "allowed " since that part is running on executors. However, this is my conscious choice to run those pieces on worker nodes.

Is that sound thinking? If not, why not?

What's the recommendation on that? or on the overall idea?

Comment: This question is very broad. I don't see how we can help with the giving information ?

Comment: @eliasah - Edited and hopefully its more concise now. I dont intend to be be generic here. very specific for my use case - read hbaes+sql execution in a streaming flow.

Comment: Are you using an HBase/Spark connector like: https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc ?

Answer (score 1):

For every streamed rec, reading from hbase and sql seems to be "too much happening in streaming app".

Anyways, you can create connection for every partition to hbase and get records and then compare. Not sure about sql. If its just another reading for every streaming record, again handle at partition level in spark.

But the above approach will be time consuming - just make sure you finish all stuff before the next batch starts.

You also mentioned converting "hbase to dataframe" and "parallel". Both seemed to be in opposite direction. Because you start with dataframe(may be reading from hbase once and then you parallelize. Hope I cleared some of your doubts

Comment: Thanks @Ramzy for quick input. the problem i am dealing with right now is to do with handling data received form hbase (at executor). I need to convert it into a dataframe and launch SQLs on it. Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: As I said, you can read all data at one go(atdriver) from hbase using newAPIHadoopRDD() and then play with dataframe. But if you are querying hbase from executors, then you can iterate the result at executor level and return the objects to form a dataframe.